# Dropzone.js: Delete image from database - Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, upload, dropzone.js

I have table `user` :

- id
- image

I used `dropzone.js` with `laravel` to upload images.
For adding images to the database it goes very well but I would like to delete the image after the upload in the database.

When I click on `Remove file` it shows me alert error as you see in the picture

[image]

[image]

**view :**

```
<form action="{{ url('/upload_image') }}" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">                     
    {{ csrf_field( ) }}
</form>
<script> 
            Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
              addRemoveLinks: true,
              init: function() {
              this.on("removedfile", function(file) {

                          var name = file.name;   
                          //alert(name);     
                          $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: "{{action('UserController@deleteFile')}}",
                          data: { 
                              image: name
                          },

                          success:function(data)
                          {
                           alert("success");

                          }
                          error: function(){
                            alert('error');
                          }

                      });
              });
            }
          };

        </script>
```

**Controller :**

```
public function upload_image(Request $request){

        $user = new User();
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $custom_file_name = uniqid().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $file->storeAs('public/',$custom_file_name);
        $user->image = $custom_file_name;
        $user->save();
        return redirect('upload/create');

    }

    public function deleteFile(Request $request){
        $title=$request->image;
        $user = User::where('image','=',$title)->delete();

        return ['success' => 'success'];
    }
```

Comment: The error is on your server. Please post your Laravel logs so you can see what the error is.

Comment: @Jeff.  it shows me, 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) public/deleteFile`

Comment: Yes, you need to know what that internal server error is.  It would be in the laravel logs in `/storage/logs`.